# how to open Whatsapp business in android

Tags: android

I am using this code to share text to a specific number in whatsapp from my android app

```
private fun shareTextOnWhatsapp(message: String, phoneNumber: String) {
        val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phoneNumber"+"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        i.data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(i)
    }
```

It works totally fine. But what I have to do is that if user has [Whatsapp Business](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp.w4b) installed in his phone then it should open **whatsapp business** instead of default [whatsapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp). Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to do it

Whatsapp Business package

```
const val WHATSAPP_BUSINESS_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.whatsapp.w4b"
```

Then i checked if whatsapp business is installed or not and then called the helper functions accordingly

```
            // if whatsapp business is installed
            if (isAppInstalled(WHATSAPP_BUSINESS_PACKAGE_NAME, this)) {
                shareTextOnWhatsappBusiness(shareText)
            } else { // share text to default whatsapp
                shareTextOnWhatsapp(shareText, order.user.mobile)
            }
```

These are two functions being called from code shared above

```
    private fun shareTextOnWhatsapp(message: String, phoneNumber: String) {
        val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phoneNumber"+"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        i.data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(i)
    }

    // tells if an app with specific packagename is installed or not
    fun isAppInstalled(packageName: String, context: Context): Boolean {
        return try {
            val packageManager = context.packageManager
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
            true
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            false
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind that if you are supporting `Android 11` then `packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)` will always return false
You will have to add this in `manifest` file

```
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
    </queries>
```

As it is mentioned in [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility)

> Android 11 changes how apps can query and interact with other apps
> that the user has installed on a device